# SQL Server Bad query performance: Bad Rows Estimate, but Statistic is accurate?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Trying to determine why a particular query is notably slow.  This query shares features with other notably slow queries, so speeding this one up will give me the tools to speed other queries up.

It's a bit of a complicated query, with 5 `INNER JOIN`s, but the first part that seems odd to me is that my first join is underestimating the memory grant, which is causing a spill during the Hash Match.

The first part of the query is estimating the number of rows returned for the query as 98,706, which is off by a factor of 10 (the true number of rows for that query is 874,215.)

I ran `sp_BlitzIndex` on the `IRItemAnswer_Info` table, and confirmed that for the key being used by the table (IRItemAnswerInfo_DGItemID_AnswerBoolean) and the parameter in question (Leading Column Name DGItemID = 1907) the statistic is correct (874,215 rows).  This is because we run a `UPDATE STATISTICS IRItemAnswer_Info WITH FULLSCAN` weekly during off-hours, to ensure that statistics are as correct as can reasonably be.

What else can I look to as the possible cause of the bad rows estimate?  The Index exactly covers the query, so I'm confused why the estimate is off, causing an insufficient memory grant?

[image: Execution Plan] [image]

`IRItemAnswer_Info` does have one significantly large column: `AnswerValue`, designed to hold rich-text content.  The other columns are much more reasonably sized.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IRItemAnswer_Info](
    [ItemAnswerSID] [dbo].[T_SidDom] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DGItemID] [dbo].[T_SidDom] NULL,
    [IncidentID] [dbo].[T_SidDom] NULL,
    [IRPhaseID] [dbo].[T_SidDom] NULL,
    [AnswerTypeID] [dbo].[T_SidDom] NULL,
    [AnswerSourceID] [dbo].[T_SidDom] NULL,
    [AnswerValue] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [AnswerCode] [dbo].[T_CodeDom] NULL,
    [AnswerLabel] [dbo].[T_LabelDom] NULL,
    [IndividualReviewFlag] [dbo].[T_BooleanDom] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [dbo].[T_UseridDom] NULL,
    [AnswerBoolean] [dbo].[T_BooleanDom] NULL,
    [CallingItemID] [dbo].[T_SidDom] NULL,
    [ClearOnDeident] [dbo].[T_BooleanDom] NULL,
    [Deidentified] [dbo].[T_BooleanDom] NULL,
    [Answer_AdditionalInfo] [dbo].[T_DescDom] NULL,
    [SubRowPosition] [tinyint] NULL
)
```

[The Actual Execution Plan for the full query that I'm troubleshooting](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryHAnpYUF)

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (IRItemAnswer_Info,IRItemAnswerInfo_DGItemID_AnswerBoolean) WITH DENSITY_VECTOR
```

returns the following:
[image: returns the following]

It's a large query with lots of indexes, so I'll do my best here:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IRItemAnswerInfo_DGItemID_AnswerBoolean] ON [dbo].[IRItemAnswer_Info]
(
    [DGItemID] ASC,
    [AnswerBoolean] ASC
)
INCLUDE([IncidentID],[AnswerSourceID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Incident_Info_Date_IDPhaseIDTimeFacDeptCreated] ON [dbo].[Incident_Info]
(
    [IncidentDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE([IncidentSid],[IRPhaseId],[IncidentTime],[FacilityId],[DepartmentId],[CreatedByUserID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [indIncidentType_XRef_IncidentTypeNodeID] ON [dbo].[IncidentType_XRef]
(
    [IncidentTypeNodeID] ASC
)
INCLUDE([IncidentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [indIRAlternative_Info_AltSID] ON [dbo].[IRAlternative_Info]
(
    [AltSID] ASC
)
INCLUDE([AltLabel]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [indIncidentTypeHierarchy_Code_NodeLeftNodeRightNodeLevel] ON [dbo].[IncidentTypeHierarchy_Code]
(
    [NodeLeft] ASC,
    [NodeRight] ASC,
    [NodeLevel] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[IncidentTypeHierarchy_Code] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_IncidentTypeHierarchy_Code] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IncidentTypeNodeSID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[IRDGroupItem_Info] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_IRDGroupItem_Info] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DGItemSID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` definitions of all tables that are involved. Do you have any unnecessarily and excessively-sized columns (e.g. `nvarchar(max)` or `nvarchar(4000)` for storing short-strings?)

Comment: Updated the question with the `CREATE TABLE` for the table that has an oversized field.  The other user-defined fields are much smaller (T_BooleanDom is BIT, T_SidDom is INT, T_CodeDom is varchar(10), T_LabelDom is varchar(50) and T_DescDom is varchar(255))

Comment: Please share the query plan (actual not estimated) via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also post the definitions of all indexes on the tables

Comment: Server does not know the value of the variable until runtime, so it's just using generic histogram density. If that average density indicates 98706 rows then it makes sense. What does `DBCC SHOWSTATISTICS WITH DENSITY_VECTOR;` show for density over those two columns?

Comment: It's a large query, and I was hoping to troubleshoot only what I believed to be the most critical portion of it, but maybe it's not possible to do this type of analysis in isolation.  If it would benefit to create a file of the details and post that, I can do that also.